# NSNotificationCenter Standard Practice?

Tags: ios, nsnotifications

Is is standard to balance the 'addObserver' with:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]
```

in the viewWillDisappear method?
For instance, when registering to receive the results of NSURLConnection events by a Data Manager class, triggered by different tabs of a TabBar (separate controllers). Each controller registers to be 'notified' of receiving results in viewDidLoad. Should each controller also unregister? It seems that if the name: of the notification is the same for all, it might cause a disaster when tab's view reappears ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every addObserver should have a remove observer.  You should be very careful not to addObservers when an observer is already added, for instance in viewDidAppear observers can be added many times and then your observing selector will get called many times.

Honestly, from the example you explain you should consider a delegate protocol.  See that here:

http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Comment: Inturbidus, Will consider the delegate protocol. You've answered the question, and more!

Comment: If sticking with the Notification center, should the 'registering' appear in the `viewWillAppear` instead? I'm noticing that it gets called when returning to a tab.

Comment: viewWillAppear runs every time the view appears.  viewDidLoad is probably more appropriate, as it is only run once when initWithNibName or init is called.

Comment: OK... Then how to 'balance'? If I'm trying to make sure a particular one doesn't get re-added, and put the `removeObserver` in the `viewWillDisappear` method (which gets called every time upon leaving the view), if coming back to the tab, how to 're-register'? Please remember the comment 'One `addObserver:self ... name:@"urlFinished"` is being used multiple times' in different view controllers.

Comment: Put your removeObserver in viewDidUnload and your addObserver in viewDidLoad.